# Malicious PHP code can run in cache. Solution?

Tags: php, caching

I have a module that I cache some details (w/c is from the input of the user) to lessen the load of my database

The way how I cache is by creating html page with the details of the user using `fwrite();`

the problem is after I try the module of the user, if I input this

```
<?php 
 echo "this is from the input of the user";
?>
```

inside the textarea. After that this details will going to cache, and then when I load the cache file the php code was executed.

The only solution that I have is to `strreplace()` this character `<?` from their input. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to **not cache like this.** For a start, `<?` is only one of several ways to inject PHP, including `<script language="PHP">` and `<?php`. Blacklists are always a bad idea.

Your caching system doesn't work in the first place in terms of performance because, by the time your PHP serving becomes a performance problem, your disk performance becomes a problem too. At that point you're not improving performance at all.

For proper caching, you want in-memory storage. Take a look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/) (and the [PHP module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)), [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), or an in-memory NoSQL solution like [Redis](http://redis.io/). These are mature projects that were designed to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks polynomial ill try to study first your suggestion, by the way have you hear about sphinx? is it good to use for my database performance to avoid caching.

Comment: @EfazAÑecohJ-ra Sphinx is an indexing engine allowing for fast searches of data, but it doesn't cache the data itself.